# How to skip to next next describe on error in Mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a bunch of `describe`s that test different parts of an API. In one section, all the tests are dependent on one test succeeding. I want to make Mocha run the first test, and if it fails, skip all following tests and run the next test suite for the next section of the API.

`mocha --bail` would stop testing altogether after the first fail, and won't continue to the next section.

[`mocha-steps`](https://github.com/rprieto/mocha-steps) is a viable solution, but I prefer not to use any external libraries. In addition, it doesn't `skip` steps after the failure, it doesn't print them altogether. Like I said, it's a viable solution, but not ideal.

What would be the best way to implement this behavior in vanilla Mocha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put what you call your "first test" in a `before` hook inside a `describe` block that contains all the other tests:

```
describe("bunch of related tests", function () {
    before(function () {
        // "first test" here
    });

    it("test 1", function () { ... });
    it("test 2", function () { ... });
    // ...
});
```

This is the proper way in "vanilla Mocha" to set a dependency between the code in the `before` hook and each of the tests. If the `before` hook fails, Mocha will report it, and it will skip all the tests in the `describe` block. If you have other tests elsewhere, they will still run.

Answer (score 2):

Although I up-voted the accepted answer, I wasn't able to get a Mocha `it` test to run inside a `before` function. Instead I had to separate the first test into its own `describe` and set a variable if the test passed, then check the variable in the `before` of the `describe` containing all the other tests.

```
let passed = false
describe('first test', function() {
  it('run the first test', function(done) {
    if (theTestPassed)
      passed = true
    done()
  })
})

describe('rest of the tests', function() {
  before(function() {
    if (!passed)
      throw new Error('skip rest of the tests')
  });
  it('second test', ...)
  it('third test', ...)
});
```